# center text inside a styled anchor

Tags: css, html

I am using an "a" tag and styling it to make it a little bigger but I cant seem to get the text to align in the middle. I tried adding padding but that just makes it bigger. Right now the text is in the top left corner but I want it dead center, any ideas?

```
<a href="#">text</a>
a {
    width: 196px;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 0px none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a {
    width: 196px;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 0px none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block; /* if more items are in line */
    line-height:64px; /* if one line of text is in question */
    text-align:center;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K4q6H/